# Could not bind to tcp://127.0.0.1:8080: Address already in use

Tags: php, tcp, laravel-4, phpwebsocket, ratchet

After developing most of the site, I needed to introduce the ability to push data from the server to client. After some research I decided to use Ratchet (I'm using Laravel 4.1).

I've implemented my pushUpdate class, but I'm having issue starting the webSocket server, My current approach to start the server is:

```
    // Run the server application through the WebSocket protocol on port 8080
    $app = new Ratchet\App('localhost', 8080);
    $app->route('/update', new pushUpdate);
    $app->route('/echo', new Ratchet\Server\EchoServer, array('*'));
    $app->run();
```

This code is ran when the page that requires push update is requested. This is the error I receive:

```
   React \ Socket \ ConnectionException
   Could not bind to tcp://127.0.0.1:8080: Address already in use
```

I haven't implemented a webSocket before, I've read the server config doc (http://socketo.me/docs/deploy#serverconfiguration) which states I can run both web and socket servers on port 8080.

any help to solving this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you have a process already using port 8080. You can see if that is the case by using "netstat -ap" to see what process is using 8080.

Comment: Yes, I have my server running on 8080. This is because I got the impression from the document I can run both "Run your website and WebSocket server on the same machine using port 8080 for WebSockets and take the chance client proxies won't block traffic"

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with Websockets so I cannot comment on that. But I am familiar with TCP, and you shouldn't share listen sockets :)

Comment: `netstat -ap` says nothing is using 8080 :P